# Backbone validation on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, backbone.js

I am using Backbone [validation](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation#built-in-validators) for validating some input fields, like so...

```
return Dialogs.Base.extend({
    template: 'container',
    validation: {
        '#input1': {
            required: true
        },
        '#input2': {
            translator: Translators.Date(),
            required: true
        },
        '#input3': {
            required: true
        }
...
```

These work fine but the `required` attribute is only satisfied when you click out of the selected input box. What if I want to validate the input as the user is typing?

Another issue is if I set the validation of one of the inputs using Jquery...

```
$("#input1").val(value);
```

This will not satisfy the `required` attribute, the validation treats the input as if it were empty even though it has a value.

Is there a way to use validation so that it catches any live change in some input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What if I want to validate the input as the user is typing?

You will need to add an event listener to the user typing, and call the `isValid` method:

[model.isValid()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isValid)